# Java Collection in C#

Tags: java, c#, .net

I'm learning some data structures and the language of the course is Java but I'm a C# guy.

Here is the code:

```
public Collection <Vertex> vertices()
{ 
     return graph.values(); 
}

Vertex is a class but how can I return a Collection in C#? Ty!
```

> Edit: I don't know if it will help but here is the class
>   Vertex.(Code already in C#)
>   Comments are in german.

```
public class Vertex : IComparable //Knotenklasse 
{
    public string name; // Name des Knoten
    public List<Edge> edges; // Nachbarn als Kantenliste
    public int nr; // Knotennummer
    public int indegree; // Eingangsgrad
    public bool seen; // Wurde der Knoten schon überprüft? 
    public int dist; // Kosten für den Knoten
    public Vertex prev; // vorheriger Knoten

    public Vertex(string s)
    {
        this.name = s;
        edges = new List<Edge>(); 
    }

    public bool hasEdge(Vertex w)
    {
        foreach (Edge e in edges)
        {
            if(e.dest == w)
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false; 
    }

    public int CompareTo(Vertex d)
    {
       if(this.dist > d.dist)
       {
           return 1;
       }
       else if(this.dist < d.dist)
       {
           return -1;
       }
       else
       {
           return 0; 
       }
    }
}
public class Edge // Kantenklasee
{
    public double cost; // Kosten
    public Vertex dest; // Zeiger auf den nächsten Knoten

    public Edge(Vertex d,double c)
    {
        this.dest = d;
        this.cost = c; 
    }
}
```

ps: the class graph in C#

```
public class Graph
{
        private Dictionary<Vertex, string> graph;  
        public Graph(Vertex d, string s)
        {
            graph = new Dictionary<Vertex, string>(); 
        }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by ` how can I return a Collection in C#`?

Comment: This makes no sense.  If the class is in java, but you are a C# guy, then why are you asking us how to do something in C#?

Comment: I'm prefering C# over Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dictionary.Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a [ValueCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8bctb9c(v=vs.110).aspx).
You can use it directly or convert it to many built in collection types in .NET.

Generally you should return a type that is as general as possible, i.e. one that knows just enough of the returned data.

```
public ICollection<Vertex> vertices()
{ 
    return graph.values(); 
}

public IList<Vertex> vertices()
{ 
    return graph.values().ToList(); 
}
```

`ICollection<T>` supports `Add`, `Remove` and `Count`.
`IList<T>` supports `Add`, `Remove`, `Count` and the ability to random access elements by their indexes

If you want to know more about different collection types and when to use them check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y3x785f(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ICollection<T>` which is an generic interface implemented by all the classes from `System.Collections.generic`:

```
public ICollection<Vertex> vertices()
{ 
     return graph.values(); 
}
```